# Vuex. How to render data from store using v-for

Tags: vue-component, vue.js

I have app with couple components. I use Vuex to store data so I could use it in different components. Now I need to render some divs using v-for. I do as follows:

VueX/Modules/shows.js

```
const state = {
 shows: [
  {
   name: 'Hard Luck',
   venue: 'The Venue',
   time: '6:00 pm'
  },
  {
   name: 'Hard Luck',
   venue: 'The Venue',
   time: '6:00 pm'
  }
 ]
}

export default {
 state
}
```

Component where I need to use data:

```
  <template>
   <div class="dashboard__details dashboard__details--shows"
      v-for="show in shows">
    <h3 class="dashboard__name">
       {{show.name}} @ {{show.venue}}      
     </h3>
     <span class="dashboard__time">{{show.time}}</span>
     <div class="dashboard__btnBlock">
       <button">Details</button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </template>

   <script>
   import { mapState } from 'vuex'
   import ReportIssue from './ReportIssue'
   import InviteFriend from './InviteFriend'

   export default {
     name: 'dashboard',
     components: { ReportIssue, InviteFriend },
     computed: mapState({
       shows: state => {
        return state.shows
       }
     })
   }
   </script>
```

It works if I have data in the component's data but I can't make it work if I store data in Vuex.

Answer (score 6):

if you are using a module then you need to of configured that within your store:

```
# your Vuex store
import shows from './VueX/Modules/shows.js'
export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    shows,
  },
  ...
```

Then when you reference it within a component you call the module not the root state:

```
export default {
  name: 'dashboard',
  components: { ReportIssue, InviteFriend },
  computed: mapState({
    shows: ({ shows }) => shows.shows
  })
}
```

You probably want to rename the module so to avoid `shows.shows` but you should get the idea

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: no worries, if it helped please mark it as the answer